# How to post in two table ReactJS

Tags: java, reactjs, post, axios, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

in the following code I post data, 
everything works fine, but I would like to be able to post, 
in 2 different table

Do you have an idea of how to fix this?

```
postbackend = () => {
 const totals =this.props.items.reduce((total,item) => item.quantity + total, 0)
 const newItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
 const { title, quantity, } = item;
  return {
    title,
    quantity,
    totals
  };
});
const config = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state, items: newItems ,totalsQty: totals , totalComplet: this.props.total , created: new Date().toISOString().slice(11,16)}),
};

const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";

fetch(url, config)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
 if (res.error) {
  alert(res.error); 
  this.props.history.replace("/OrderSummaryPaymentFalseScreen");  // Your Error Page
  } else {
  alert(`film ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
   this.props.history.push("/OderSummaryScreen"); // Your Success Page
  }
 }).catch(e => {
 console.error(e); 
 this.props.history.replace("/OrderSummaryPaymentFalseScreen");  // Your Error Page
 }).finally(() => this.setState({
 redirect: true
}));
}
```

Comment: by 2 databases, you mean 2 API right ? with 2 differents url ?

What should be the expected behavior if one post fails ?

Comment: @Alain hello , yes 2 API , wuth 2 diffrents url , it is ok for if one post fails , i need just 2 api differents

Comment: Generally, Developers don't suggest usage of Multiple Databases, instead developers use Multiple Tables. As per your question, Why don't you try to call another API call after one succeeds/ fails? Maybe you have to code another `get/ post/ put` call after the first one.

Comment: @AnglesvarCheenu hello , i dont want really use multiple databases i reformul i need to post at Second Tables

Comment: Sorry you are not clear enough. Are you posting the same data in 2 tables ? Or you want to push another data into another table ? I dont understand what is difficult. Just do a second fetch

Comment: @Alain sorry for not clear , yes the same data in 2 tables , 
I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it in the same post, it saves me from re doing a fecth

Comment: ok, just go to your backend controller, the one which handle this url (`const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";`) and when you receive a request, you write into 2 tables. If the both tables come from 2 databases from 2 distinct servers, then you will have to fetch twice